# Random timeouts in IIS7

Tags: iis-7, timeout

I have a weird problem which I think is caused by my IIS7 installation on Vista 64 bit.

I have a bunch of AJAX calls and JS dynamic file loads (~30) in a local application, and I get random timeouts (or so it seems) in my browser.

In Chrome it looks like the page just stops loading (no HDD activity), in Firefox/Firebug I can see that some of the files are being loaded but they never actually finish. When I reload the page the same occurs, but for (random) other files that must be loaded.

When I try to load one of those JS files concurrently (so during the timeout in FF) in another browser, the file loads there. So I am pretty sure the request can be handled by IIS.

I am thinking about a limit or so on simultaneous requests from the same browser which is not working correctly, but I am pretty clueless on how to solve this.

Does anyone recognize this problem and know a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I think IIS in Vista has a limit to the number of concurrent connections. http://www.lockergnome.com/windows/2006/12/04/install-iis-in-vista/

Have you tried hosting your app on Srv2008

Comment: There indeed is, but this should not be a problem because requests should be queued. I know the application works OK on other, non-server OSs (vista, win7 etc)

Comment: Requests aren't always queued, depending on your app, files will be downloaded at the same time.

Hope you get it sorted

Comment: No but IIS should queue the requests (differs from XP in which they would simply give a 'server busy' response)